# Pods custom type integration with navigation menu and current_menu_parent

Tags: pods-framework

I have a Pods type called `project`, and a Pods pages url as `project/*` (which links to a template to show the project).

I also have a normal Page which lists the projects (via a custom shortcode that loops through all the pods) and outputs on the page.

My navigation menu is simple: Home, About Us, Method, Our Work, Contact Us.

I need further guidance please on how to link up the Pods `project/*` page so that when a specific project is being displayed, the top level Projects link is highlighted with the correct wordPress class `current_menu_parent`.

Also where should the Pods page be listed in the Wordpress Appearance -> Menu, as I see no link there for the Pods type.

How can I do this please?

[image: unable to link pods custom type to nav menu]

Comment: When you edit the menu, click Screen Options in the top right corner and make sure everything is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Content Types and Pod Pages are separate from WordPress post types. They do not currently show up in the navigation menu management area. This is a feature we are working on including in the future.

https://github.com/pods-framework/pods/issues/1053